# E(X), var(X) and std dev (X)

Tags: probability

For some reason, this question didn't show properly in my previous post.

X is given by its Distribution function:
$$
F(x) =\begin{cases}
0 &x \leq 0\\
\frac{x^2}{4} &0 < x \leq 2\\
1 &x > 2
\end{cases}
$$

I'm trying to find $E(X)$, $Var(X)$ and $Std\;dev (X)$

Thanks.

Comment: Pressaumably you are working with continuous variables? [check this out](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10159/find-expected-value-using-cdf) and extend to the variance etc.

Answer (score 2):

These calculations are under the assumption that $X$ is a continuous variable and that $F(X)$ is the CDF (and not the PDF, at which point $E[X]$ is not defined due to a diverging integral). First we calculate the PDF
$$f(x) = \frac{dF(x)}{dx} = \frac{x}{2}, \quad 0<x<2$$
and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise.

The definition of the expectational value is
\begin{aligned}
E[X] & = \int_{0}^{\infty}xf(x)dx = \\
     & = \int_{0}^{2}x\frac{x}{2}dx = \\
     & = \frac{4}{3}.
\end{aligned}
The variance is defined as
\begin{aligned}
\text{Var}[X] & = E[X^2]-E[X]^2 = \\
 & = \int_{0}^{2}x^2\frac{x^2}{2}dx - \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^2\\
 & = \frac{16}{5} - \frac{16}{9} = \\
 & = \frac{64}{45}.
\end{aligned}
The variance is the standard deviation squared, which means that
\begin{aligned}
\sigma[X] = \sqrt{\text{Var}[X]} = \sqrt{\frac{64}{45}} = \frac{8}{3\sqrt{5}}.
\end{aligned}

Comment: Thank you very much, I just finished my calculations and ended up with 3/4 for E(X) also but 1.25 for the variance. I thought we needed to use f(x) which is x/2 but I see you used x^2/2.  Please clarify.

Comment: Note that the variance includes a term $E[X^2]$, so you substitute $x^2$ into $\int xf(x)dx$ where $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}$, i.e. you get $\int x^2f(x^2) dx = \int x^2\frac{x^2}{2}dx$.

Comment: Got it, thank you again.